# Grails + Spock: NullPointerException when doing addTo* on an embedded hasMany field

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, spock

I have domain class:

```
class MarketCommoditiesConfiguration extends MarketConfiguration {

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    static hasMany = ['commodities': Commodity]

    static embedded = ['commodities']

    ...
```

Doing `save` after `addToCommodities` throws the following exception.

```
|  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.types.Association.getInverseSide(Association.java:71)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.handleEmbeddedInstance(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1254)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.handleEmbeddedInstance(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1215)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.handleEmbeddedToMany(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1188)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.persistEntity(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1077)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.persistEntity(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1138)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.EntityPersister.persist(EntityPersister.java:160)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.persist(AbstractSession.java:522)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy:194)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save_closure5(GormInstanceApi.groovy:162)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:161)
    at com.apposit.terra.connect.service.MarketService.addCommodityToMarket(MarketService.groovy:248)
    at com.apposit.terra.connect.service.MarketServiceSpec.Test addCommodityToMarket creates a new next month configuration if current month's configuration doesn't exist(MarketServiceSpec.groovy:164)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `Keyword` inside `@Mock` annotation solved it. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-MongoDb-embedded-collection-causes-nullpointerexception-td4644098.html contains more involved discussion.

> I know this is super-old, but a Google search led me here whilst
>   facing the same issue.  Make sure that you have added @Mock(User) to
>   your unit test class.  In my case, I had multiple levels of embedded
>   domain classes, and each of them had to be mocked.
>     **- clarkdustin**